# Change the time by country in Blogger

Tags: javascript, blogger

Input I would like to accomplish this blogger.

I need to put in some widget (could be with javascript) or from a post (post title and date of dynamics) the following:

Example 1 - 25/05/2016 16:00

Example 1 - 25.05.2016 20:00

The problem is that I need the time change depending on the country, as it will be as a guide channel (on schedule) visitors should be able to see the exact time of transmission according to your country.

I wonder if this is possible with javascript or something? as blogger it does not allow many modifications.

Where do I start? terms which look for in Google?

Comment: You can get the local GMT offset: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: @EvanTrimboli I'm reading the documentation "http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/" and I think it could serve, the problem is I have no idea how to use this to change the date of the post in blogger or within a widget for more I read the official documentation does not say as finally show the user, I am very unfortunately lost with javascript.